# Sorting GridView with ObjectDataSource Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, objectdatasource

I am following a tutorial to enable sorting in a GridView that has an objectdatasource as it's datasource.  http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/gridview-objectdatasource-linq-paging-and-sorting

It seems pretty straight forward, but when I run the code,

```
public List<tbl_Batch> SelectAllList(string sSortType, int iBeginRowIndex, int iMaximumRows)
    {

        using (TestEntities dbContext = new TestEntities())
        {

            var query = from q in dbContext.tbl_Batch
                        select q;     // sort     
            query = SelectAllSort(query, sSortType);     // filter the list if needed    
            query = SelectAllQuery(query);     // paginate    
            query = query.Skip(iBeginRowIndex).Take(iMaximumRows);     // execute the query and convert to list    
            return query.ToList();

        }
    }
```

when it gets to the last line return query.ToList(); I'm getting the error message: Limit must have a non-negative value.
Parameter name: limit
I don't know what is causing this error, and I can't find any information about it anywhere.

Here's the code for my GridView can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="intBatchID" 
        AllowPaging="True" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SkinID="NOCTS" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" 
        BorderStyle="Solid" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#990033" Width="1000px" 
        DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
     <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>      
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="intBatchID" HeaderText="Batch ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="TestPage1.aspx?intBatchID={0}" DataTextField="intBatchID" />      
        <asp:BoundField DataField="vcharName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="vcharName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dtmScheduled" HeaderText="Date Scheduled" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="dtmScheduled" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intBatchPriorityLevel" 
            HeaderText="Priority Level" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="intBatchPriorityLevel" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" PageButtonCount="4" PreviousPageText="Previous" NextPageText="Next" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />        
</asp:GridView> 
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="SelectAllList" TypeName="NOCTSWebApplication.App_Code.Class3" 
    OnSelected="ObjectDataSource1_Selected" EnablePaging="True" 
    MaximumRowsParameterName="iMaximumRows" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    StartRowIndexParameterName="iBeginRowIndex" SortParameterName="sSortType">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="sSortType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="iBeginRowIndex" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="iMaximumRows" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

If you need anymore of my code let me know.
Here's the rest of my code:

```
private IQueryable<tbl_Batch> SelectAllQuery(IQueryable<tbl_Batch> query)
    {       
        return query;
    }

    private IQueryable<tbl_Batch> SelectAllSort(IQueryable<tbl_Batch> query, string sSortType)
        {
            using (TestEntities dbContext = new TestEntities())
                {
                        bool bIsSortDescending = false;    
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sSortType))    
                    {
                            string[] sValues = sSortType.Split(' ');        
                                if (sValues.Length > 1)        
                                {            
                                    if (sValues[1].ToUpper() == "DESC")            
                                    {                
                                       bIsSortDescending = true;            
                                    }        
                                }    
                    }     
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sSortType))    
                    {
                            query = dbContext.tbl_Batch.OrderBy(sSortType);    
                    }    
                    else    
                    {        // use a default sort here        
                    if (bIsSortDescending)        
                    {            
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(q => q.intBatchID);        
                    }        
                    else        
                    {            
                     query = query.OrderBy(q => q.vcharName);        
                    }    
                }     
                    return query;
        }
    }

    public int SelectCount()
    {
        using (TestEntities dbContext = new TestEntities())
        {

            var query = from q in dbContext.tbl_Batch
                        select q;
            query = SelectAllQuery(query);     // execute the query and return the count    
            return query.Count();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `SelectAllQuery` - what is it? Also check values of paging limit (iMaximumRows).

Comment: @WiktorZychla the value of iMaxiumumRows is -1.  I added the rest of my code so you could see SelectAllQuery.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't take -1 rows out of result set. This is why you get an exception.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Do you know why it's doing that, or do you know how I fix it?  I'm really new to linq and the objectdatasource.

Comment: You should definitely delete the SelectParameters section of your data source. You don't need it as parameters are named above.

Comment: I did that.  Now I'm getting the error message: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: I think your gridview lacks the PageSize parameter value.

Comment: @WiktorZychla that previous error didn't have anything to do wwith this sorry.  I did remove the select parameters and I'm still getting the same error message: Limit must have a non-negative value.
Parameter name: limit.  Do you have any other ideas of what I need to do?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I added a page size to the GridView, but still the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least some elements missing in your set up.

First, remove `SelectParameters` from the `ObjectDataSource`.
Then make sure that you set `PageSize` in the grid.
At last, add `SelectCountMethod = "SelectCount"` to `ObjectDataSource`.

If you need a concise example on what properties are required to get proper results, consult one of examples I made years ago for my students:

http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~wzychla/ra2829/example3a.zip

There are two pages there, `Default.aspx` shows how to pair `ObjectDataSource` with `GridView` and `DetailsView` while `Default2.aspx` shows how to pair `ObjectDataSource` with `ListView`.

Comment: I don't completely understand how your example works?  I'm used to working with a visual model, and I don't understand how you are making sorting work in yours?  I got paging to work in my project by adding selectcountmethod as you suggested.  The only thing not working now is Sorting.  I'm getting the error message: he ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. When it goes back into SelectAllSort method.  Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: Your sorting method is wrong, it creates yet another db context while it should operate on the existing. Formally: instead of `query = bbContext.tbl_Batch.OrderBy(sSortType);` you should have `query = query.OrderBy( sSortType )`. This will work only if you include dynamic linq (http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)